# How to process the response of an XMLHttpRequest where the responseText is a compressed (gzip) format

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, gzip

I very much appreciate anyone looking at this question and any helpful responses.

I am exploring the possibility of trying to load a text file from an external site to my site. The text file has been compressed or deflated with gzip, so the path looks like https://host/filename.txt.gz

I am trying to load the contents with a XMLHttpRequest, and then I am trying to decompress/inflate the contents using this https://github.com/augustl/js-inflate library. The response content-type is Application/Octet-stream.

So, my problem is that however the responseText is decoded, a lot of the characters produced are the "replacement character" (code 65533, or �). It is my understanding that this is produced when the decoder can't process the byte sequence.

The text files I am trying to decode/decompress are certainly valid, because if I download them they can be decompressed and viewed just fine.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://host.something/filename.txt.gz');
request.onload = function() {
    // the request text is all, there, looking like ��`�P GSE43615_non_normalized.txt t�I�,A�$���}���yXFf����D��...
    var infwated = JSInflate.inflate(request.responseText);  // (note: tried to base64decode the response first in case that's it.  it doesn't seem to be)
    // the 'inflated' result comes back as an empty string.  
    // As I debug the JSInflate library, it appears the the library is looking for bytes to signal how the text should be processed.
    // The code breaks out of the processing in the first conditional because the byte is not recognized
    console.log(infwated || 'failed');  // it's 'failed'
            }
request.send();
```

I hope I explained this so it makes sense. So, my questions are:

> Is what I am trying to do possible? (emphasis on possible, as opposed to reasonable)
>
> If so, the vague question is, how can I read the response so it can be processed and decompressed? More specifically, how can text be 'read' in from an XMLHttpWebRequest in a way that an inflating algorithm can work with it?

Thanks a lot for any help!!!

Comment: That library seems to be deprecated... try one of the suggested ones instead?

Comment: Yes, it is deprecated.  It was my impression that is because the author is no longer maintaining it.  The author's test cases still pass, so I assumed it's functional.  I did try other libraries with the same result.  I chose the library I did for it's relative simplicity and light-weightness compared to the others.  Do you think the fault is possibly not with the response, but with the inflating algorithm?

Comment: That might well be it... also, make sure you are setting the correct responseType, perhaps?  It is by default "text"... maybe it should be "blob"?

Comment: Yep, the response type was it!  It seems the most concise way was to have a response type of arraybuffer, and the Pako library has an API that accepts that   ```
var compressed= new Uint8Array(req.response);
  var inflated = pako.inflate(compressedData, {to: "string"});
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'll created an answer for this, mind accepting it?

Comment: Sure thing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct responseType. "Text" is default, perhaps it should be "blob"?